# I am populating my dropdown from DB but after selecting I am getting null value in my method present in my java code when submit button is clicked

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I am populating my dropdown from DB but after selecting I am getting null value in my method present in my java code when submit button is clicked.
Though, if I am hard coding values in my dropdown, whole functionality is working perfectly. Please, tell me what I am doing wrong?

Java Code for passing List value obtained from DB which I am passing to my JSP:

```
    EventService eventService = new EventServiceImpl();
    List<Event> theEvents = eventService.showEventListMethod();

    // add the event list to the model
    theModel.addAttribute("event", theEvents);

    return "eventPostponeCancelCompletePage";
```

My JSP form where I am selecting value from dropdown:

```
    <form action = "eventCancelCompleteMethod" modelAttribute="event" method = "post">
    <table id="table" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td width="50%">Event Name: </td>
    <td width="50%">
    <select name="eventName">
    <c:forEach var="tempEvent" items="${event}">
        <option value="tempEvent.eventName">${tempEvent.eventName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select> 

    <!-- <select name="eventName">
        <option value="Birthday Party for May">Birthday party for May</option>

    </select>  -->

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" width="34%" >
    <!-- <input type = "submit" value = "Postpone"/> -->
    <input class="btn btn-default custom" type = "button" value = "Postpone Event" onclick="openPage('showPostponeEventPage')"/>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="33%">
    <input class="btn btn-default custom" type = "submit" value = "Cancel/Complete Event"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Java method which will be called once submit button is clicked:

```
@PostMapping("/eventCancelCompleteMethod")
public String eventCancelCompleteMethod(@ModelAttribute("event") Event theEvent)
{
    EventService eventService = new EventServiceImpl();
    System.out.println("Event Name: "+theEvent.eventName);
    //theEvent.setEventName("New testing event July");
    theEvent.setEventState("inactive");

    System.out.println("New Event Data: "+theEvent);

    System.out.println("Successfully Cancelled/Completed the event");

    String action = eventService.eventCancelCompleteMethod(theEvent.eventName, theEvent.eventState);
    System.out.println("Action: " + action);

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
    {
        System.out.println("Successfully added contributor data!!");
        return "redirect:/showEventPostponeCancelComplete";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to add!!");
        return "redirect:/showEventPostponeCancelComplete";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use form:select as below:

```
<form:select path="BEAN.YourBeanAttrName" style='width: 110px;' id="">
    <form:options items="${FORM.actionList}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="value"/>
</form:select>
```